# read a csv into a list with one command and then read in it

Tags: python

is it possible to read a csv like this:

```
1,22,5
1,33,9
3,44,5
4,32,5
5,53,5
6,64,5
7,12,7
```

with one command to a list with the format `[(1,22,5),...]`?

And how can I search in the list after that to get e.g. all elemente where the first column is a 1?

For example: get all with row1 == 1 will return

```
1,22,5
1,33,9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    rows = [[int(el) for el in row] for row in csv.reader(f)]


>>> rows
[[1, 22, 5], [1, 33, 9], [3, 44, 5], [4, 32, 5], [5, 53, 5], [6, 64, 5], [7, 12, 7]]
>>> [row for row in rows if row[0] == 1]
[[1, 22, 5], [1, 33, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

```
import csv
csv_rows = list(csv.reader(sys.stdin))
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html